# Wordpress site doesn't work properly

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem is that I have made a wordpress site on localhost, than I have copied everything to a 000webhost.com domain, changed every post and page IDs, but the site doesn't work on the domain after I log off my wordpress account.

The site has language change option which is works with a languageID cookie (value is 0 if english, and 1 if hungarian). I click on the flag of the language, the cookie value is change properly and the site language too, but when I load another page, the language stays the old. The page sees the cookies (I watched it in the Application->Cookies menu), and after a hard reload, the language changes. The path is / and I gave an expiration date too.

The other strange things is that if I overwrite the header.php file, the header won't change its contant on the pages exept the front page.

I can't upload the site's files cause they are very huge, but I can tell more things that could help you to solve my problem:

- The pages have their own .php files with their slug (like page-some-slug.php)
- The permalinks are like www.mysite.com/pagename
- Everything works fine on localhost with or without logged in with my wordpress account
- I have changed only the page and post ID-s in the code
- I have changed the header.php files, but the header on the pages didn't changed even after hard reload the browser

If you could help, please help me!

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned that the WordPress script worked in your localhost and now it's not working on 000webhost.com a free web hosting services? right?

- The issue is the free web host, They have restrict free users access for limited feature.
- Maybe they don't allow .htaccess and session creation.
- Most things are restricted, if your script works on localhost sure it will work live server. You need to get a paid hosting to unlock all the features.

You can confirm with the 000webhost.com, what are they restricted with free hosting users.